# Imported py file can't find modules it uses

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have an `util.py` file. 
There's a function `func` in it:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def delete_columns(data, columns):
    """
    Deletes all columns in data 
    """
    for column in columns:
        del data[column]
```

If I import it in my jupyter notebook and implement it - everything is OK.

But then I deside to make another `util2` which calls `util`:

```
import numpy as np
from util import *
def clean(data):
    data = data[np.isfinite(data.lol)]
    delete_columns(data=data, columns= ['1','2','3'])
```

And **NOW**, when i call it from jupyter it finishes with:

```
----> 7 from user_functions import *
      8 def clean_1(data):
      9     data = data[np.isfinite(data.lol)]

NameError: name 'np' is not defined
```

What's wrong? Each file imports all modules!

Comment: When you imported `numpy` in `util.py` did you rerun it?

Comment: If `util.py` calls something from `numpy`, then that file has to `import numpy` itself.

Comment: @RaviKumar What do you mean? How can i return a module?

Comment: `import numpy as np` in `util.py` should have worked. Are you sure that's exactly what you had?

Comment: @Kevin Yes. I ll edit the question.

Comment: @LadenkovVladislav No, I said rerun. There is an option to run a cell in jupyter notebook right?

Comment: @RaviKumar furthemore, merely re-running the cell that imports `util` will not work, since it is already loaded. You need to use `importlib.reload` or use the [`autoreload`](https://ipython.org/ipython-doc/3/config/extensions/autoreload.html) option in ipython.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should import `np` in modules that's using it, change your `util.py` to this:

```
import numpy as np

def func(l):
    a = np.array(l)
    return a
```

UPDATE: make sure you have numpy for python3 installed (open python3 interpreter (make sure it's python3) and import numpy see if it works (also make sure jupiter is using python 3)

Comment: As i said in my answer, I already tried this. This didn't help

Comment: ahh sorry, are you sure you have numpy for python3 installed? try importing it in python3 interpreter (make sure it's not python2)

Comment: @aliva I'm almost certain that the root-cause of the issue is that they are working in the same jupyter notebook kernel session without explicitely `reload`ing the module.

Comment: I have updated the question. My bad. I thought the previous version would had been enough for problem solving